# Add Javadoc/source to Joda-Time when imported as Maven dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies, javadoc, jodatime

I'm new to Maven and the Joda-Time library.
Is there a simple way to add Javadoc/source code to the Joda-Time library when I import it with Maven?

This is what I added to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
  <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse with the Maven Plugin you'll find this setting under: *Preferences / Maven / Download Artifact Sources* and *Download Artifact JavaDoc*

Comment: Thank you so much! Hard to believe that this easy solution is so hard to find with google.

Answer (score 1):

For Netbeans8 IDE In Your maven project:

- Choose services folder.
- Click 'Maven Repositories'.
- Click 'Central Repository'.
- Find joda-time.
- Double click joda-time artifact group.
- Double click the joda-time artifact.
- Choose your version number.
- Right click and add dependency.
- It will then be added to your pom.xml and be
  downloaded and compiled into your project.